# Angular material basic snackbar without button

Tags: angular, angular-material, snackbar

So Angular Material has two main ways of calling a SnackBar. The one way is where you call a basic default SnackBar:

```
snackbar.open('Message archived', 'Undo', {
  duration: 3000
});
```

The other way is where you call a component as a SnackBar:

```
snackbar.openFromComponent(MessageArchivedComponent, {
  data: 'some data'
});
```

Now my question is, how do I call the basic one (without the use of a component) but without the `'Undo'` button. I can do this:

```
snackBar.open('Message archived');
```

But then how do I adjust the duration and all the other properties?

https://material.angular.io/components/snack-bar/overview

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this.

```
snackbar.open('Message archived', '', {
  duration: 3000,
  extraClasses :['test']
});
```

add styles to test class so that the text will be aligned.

If extraClasses is not working, use panelClass instead

CSS class.

```
.test .mat-simple-snackbar{justify-content: center;}
```

Comment: The problem with this is that you can't get the text in the center, it still holds a space for the button. How do you apply text-align: center to this?

Comment: You need to use panelClass not extraClasses. But now this does not solve the problem. Creating the .test{text-align:center} does not work hey

Comment: There we go thank you very much man! :) Just change your extraClasses to panelClass. extraClasses has long been deprecated and does not work at all. At least not on stackblitz

Answer (score 3):

**Update 2020**

The accepted answer seems not to be correct anymore.
If someone stumples upon the same problem, here is what works for me:

Create the snackbar with the `panelClass` property as normally.

```js
// xy.component.ts

this.snackBar.open('Message', '', {
    duration: 3000,
    panelClass: ['simple-snack-bar']
}
```

Since the custom CSS gets applied to the snack bar container , you have to select the Angular Material snack bar class to override the style.

```css
/* 
styles.css - if you don't want to use ::ng-deep (what is not recomended),
then you are forced to put your styles in the global scope
*/

.simple-snack-bar .mat-simple-snackbar {
  justify-content: center;
}
```